# Jquery SlideToggle .click problem

Tags: jquery

Im using the following:

```
$(function() {
    $(".StaffSubjectClassNav ul").hide();
        $('.StaffSubjectClassNav h3').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('100');
    });
});
```

On the following HTML:

```
<h3><a href="link">Link</a></h3>
<ul>
<li>Link1</li>
<li>Link2</li>
<li>Link3</li>
</ul>
```

It works perfectly, hides the `<UL>` and shows it when I click on the `<H3>`.

However `<a>` is also a link, how can I set the script so that if they click the `<a>` inside the `<H3>` it doesn't slideToggle?

Comment: Don’t you think that’s a little bit confusing for the user?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me - clicking the link just goes to the link (in both IE and Firefox). Aside from that, I agree with Gumbo - it's pretty confusing from a usability point of view.

Comment: Not really in the way its presented.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `h3` in the `a` and add the action to the link and return `false`. For example:

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".StaffSubjectClassNav ul").hide();
    $('#h3_link').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('100');
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="link" id="h3_link"><h3>Link</h3></a>
<ul>
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
    <li>Link3</li>
</ul>
```

You might just have to change your CSS a little bit. But, this is the correct way to do it. Links are meant to be clicked, not H3 tags.

Comment: The `A` element does not allow block level elements such like `H3` as a child.